# VB.NET MessageBox using Code Behind variables @ OnClick

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-web-developer

I have the following procedure which when the Select Button is clicked returns a number of values from the row in the GridView which the Select Button was clicked in. These values are stored as variables. This procedure executes as part of code behind (VB). I would like to pass the variable BodyOfEmail to the non-code behind (aspx) page and create a pop up window which lists the values. I guess the main issue I am having a hard time with is how to link to pop up message to this onclick procedure.

```
Public BodyOfEmail As String

Protected Sub GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView2.SelectedIndexChanged, GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
  Dim Number, BodyOfEmail, FullName As String
  Dim RowValue As Double

  RowValue = GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value - 1
  Number = GridView1.Rows(RowValue).Cells(5).Text.ToString
  FullName = GridView1.Rows(RowValue).Cells(25).Text.ToString
  BodyOfEmail = Number & " " & FullName
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: If Jason Meckley (below) is correct, can anyone detail how I can convert the above code to JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot mix and match client and server code. it's either javascript or VB. you can use registerscript methods to dynamically generate javascript when the page is rendered and you can send/get data from the server on the client using ajax.

Comment: Hmmm.. I was under the impression I could pass a variable from the server side to the client side, in this case using <%# BodyOfEmail %>?

Comment: You can do that although you are not binding (#) simply writing so `<%=BodyOfEmail%>`. then you also need to consider escaped characters, line breaks, etc.